# How to show wordpress page between 10am to 5pm?

Tags: wordpress, datetime, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm creating a car booking website for my cousin and i have created it using wordpress, he wan't the booking page to be available between 10am to 5pm only. Otherwise the page must show booking hour ends. Please give me idea for this.

Comment: What an awful idea. Being able to to things 24/7 is one of the primary advantages of the online experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up with this, just put this code snippet inside your `functions.php`

```
add_filter('the_content', 'check_time');
function check_time($content)
{
    $pagename = get_query_var('pagename');
    if($pagename=='booking_page') // page name assumed 'booking_page' here
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka'); // set your timezone if it was not set, currently it's mine
        $currentTime=strtotime(date("H:i", time()));
        $start=strtotime("10:00"); // 10am
        $end=strtotime("17:00"); // 5pm

        if($currentTime >= $start && $currentTime <= $end)
        {
            return $content; // return the original content, it's intime
        }
        else
        {
            $content="Booking hour ends!"; // change the content to "Booking hour ends!"
        }

    }
    return $content;
}
```

I've tested it and working perfectly, but not sure if this is the perfect way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can check with current time in index.php itself. If the current time is not between your specified time redirect to the page that shows some  message